# From geoJSON to Array

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, multidimensional-array, geojson

The real issue was that i could not seem to be able to set the value inside the coordinates.

The start of the JSON looks something like this.

```
{  
    "path":{  
        "type":"FeatureCollection",
        "features":[  
            {  
                "geometry":{  
                    "type":"LineString",
                    "coordinates":[  
                        [  
                            10.4048129700337,
                            63.416688738540316
                        ],
                        [  
                            10.404757623420094,
                            63.4167327334674
                        ]
                    ]
                },
                "type":"Feature",
                "id":85624,
                "properties":{  
                    "flags":[  

                    ],
                    "z":2.0,
                    "m":5.62957707088913e-06,
                    "target":85621,
                    "buildingId":43
                }
            }
```

When I ran the code it gave me

> "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property '0' of undefined" on 
>   remakeObj[i].coordinates[j][k] = coordinates[j][k];

This is now solved. I solved it this way.

```
parseToObjects: function (data) {
    var remakeObj = [];
    var features = data.path.features;
    for (var i in features) {
        remakeObj[i] = {
            flooring: "",
            meters: "",
            coordinates: []
        };

        var coordinates = features[i].geometry.coordinates;

        for (var j in coordinates) {
            remakeObj[i].coordinates[j] = [];
            for (var k in coordinates[j]) {

                remakeObj[i].coordinates[j][k] = coordinates[j][k];
                remakeObj[i].flooring = features[i].properties.z;
                remakeObj[i].meters = features[i].properties.m;

            }
        }

    }
    console.log(remakeObj);
    return remakeObj;
}
```

Comment: don't use for in use a for loop with index, then you will do it right.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays in `JavaScript` are practically [hash tables](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table) (think of it like buckets that contain values and a key in order to access it in a way) and not serially number-indexed only arrays.

Although numeric indexes as keys are allowed, the array can contain as well as keys of other types (`string` type etc.).

Therefore, the index `0` will not return the first element of the array, but the value element stored `myArray[0]`, if any (in your case, there is not any and this is why you get the error).

You need to iterate the array using the keys set in order to access all of the values serially:

```
for (var key in myArray) {
    var y = myArray[key]; //Index it like this, use it similarly.
}
```

UPDATE: This is what you could possibly do (Warning: Untested code):

```
for (var featuresKey in features) {
    remakeObj[featuresKey] = [features.length];
    var coordinates = features[featuresKey].geometry.coordinates;
    remakeObj[featuresKey].coordinates = new Array(coordinates.length);

    for (var coordinatesKey in coordinates) {

        for (var innerCoordinatesKey in coordinates[coordinatesKey]) {
            remakeObj[featuresKey].coordinates[coordinatesKey][innerCoordinatesKey] =
                coordinates[coordinatesKey][innerCoordinatesKey];
            remakeObj[featuresKey].flooring = features[featuresKey].properties.z;
            remakeObj[featuresKey].meters = features[featuresKey].properties.m;


        }

    }

}
```

Comment: Could you give an example?  It works iterating and setting all the values except the coordinates.

Comment: Do not post your code in the comments.
Take a `StackOverflow` tour: http://stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Just a small comment: I noticed that you although having satisfying answers in all of your questions, you do not vote those answers as best. The users in this community are putting some time and effort in order to give you a good answer that shines. Consider saying "thank you" by voting their answers as best (http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers). You are not forced to, but it would be nice. And again, take the SO tour. It will help you post better questions and be a more effective part of the community.

Comment: Upvoting is different that choosing an answer as best. Right near an answer, there is a tick button. If you press on it, you choose an answer as best. :)

Comment: I gave you one for your trouble :)  Tho it did not solve the problem entirely.

Comment: Happy you made it! :)